# Automate Generate Scripts Wizard in SQL2008

Tags: sql, scripting, ssms

Problem:  how to automate a Generate Scripts in SQL2008 Management Studio:

ie right click on database, Tasks, Generate Scripts

All Tables
All Stored Procs

Create drop statements
Don't use USE statement
Generate data

This is a 20sec process to do by hand.. needs automating :-)  I don't really want to  code it in C# in SQL Server Management Objects (SMO).

Maybe I'll have to use AutoHotKey :-)

Comment: Uhh… I actually did exactly this with AutoHotkey. I stopped using the script, though, because the stakes were too high if it were to ever go awry and start dropping the wrong tables from the wrong database, etc. I'm guessing SMO is not going to work on Express?

Comment: Hi Jay.. yes, I've got other AutoHotKey scripts which do stop running or change character if something else happens.. playing with fire!  I'm not running express, so that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use SMO - it's the right thing to do and you know it!

Comment: :-) He he.. right... I'll be looking at SMO tomorrow I guess then!

Comment: If only you could script scripting.  :)  Where's the sp_generatescriptforobjects stored procedure when you need it?  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at DBSourceTools. http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com
It's an open-source scripting engine for SQL Server Databases that uses SMO.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken Will A's advice and tried scripting.. [SQL Server Management Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384649/sql-server-management-objects)

nearly there :-)