# SQL Server Management Objects

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ssms

Am getting the same error on the code below using either trusted or SQL logins:

> VS2010, Console app .NET4, Win XP. SQL2005 Full.

Bombs on the transfer.TransferData

> ERROR : errorCode=-1073548784 description=Executing the query ""
>   failed with the following error: "Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {19E353EF-DAF4-45D8-9A04-FB7F7798DCA7} failed due
>   to the following error: 80040154.". Possible failure reasons: Problems
>   with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not
>   set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

this feels like security. Any thoughts would be awesome!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;


namespace GenerateScripts
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                ServerConnection sourceConnection = new ServerConnection("localhost");
                Server sourceServer = new Server(sourceConnection);
                //sourceServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
                //sourceServer.ConnectionContext.Login = "3tier";
                //sourceServer.ConnectionContext.Password = "3tier";
                Database sourceDatabase = sourceServer.Databases["3tier"];


                // destination
                ServerConnection destinationConnection = new ServerConnection("localhost");
                Server destinationServer = new Server(destinationConnection);
                //destinationServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
                //destinationServer.ConnectionContext.Login = "3tier2";
                //destinationServer.ConnectionContext.Password = "3tier2";
                Database destinationDatabase = destinationServer.Databases["3tier2"];

                Transfer transfer = new Transfer(sourceDatabase);
                transfer.CopyAllObjects = false;
                transfer.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = false;
                transfer.UseDestinationTransaction = true;

                transfer.CopyAllDefaults = true;
                transfer.Options.Indexes = true;
                transfer.Options.DriAll = true;
                transfer.CopyAllDefaults = true;

                transfer.Options.AnsiFile = true;
                transfer.Options.SchemaQualify = true;
                transfer.Options.WithDependencies = false;
                transfer.CreateTargetDatabase = false;
                transfer.CopySchema = true;
                transfer.CopyData = true;

                transfer.DestinationServer = "localhost";
                transfer.DestinationDatabase = "3tier2";
                transfer.DestinationLoginSecure = false;
                transfer.DestinationLogin = "3tier2";
                transfer.DestinationPassword = "3tier2";

                transfer.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
                transfer.TransferData();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the same case but i had a similar problem and it was related to **SQLTaskConnectionOleDb** class registration corruption,

i've solved it by running

```
regsvr32 "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\SQLTaskConnections.dll"
```

in command prompt.