# How to take SQL Server 2012 schema + data dump using command prompt

Tags: sql-server-2012, schema, command-prompt, data-dump

I have a database in SQL Server 2012. Now I am looking for some windows commands that will generate an .sql file for the schema[create statement] and another .sql file for the data[insert statement] of that database. I need to do this using command prompt. So I can't use the Generate Scripts option provided in SQL Server Management Studio.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use PowerShell and SMO. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488666/how-to-automate-script-generation-using-smo-in-sql-server.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen Mostert but I wanted something like the answer below. Can u help with something like this for data dump also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema dump from command-line can be done using [SQLPackage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx). The command is -

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /action:Extract /tf:<drive:\folder_name\file_name.dacpac> /SourceConnectionString:"Data Source=<server_name>;Initial Catalog=<db_name>;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False; /su:<user_name> /sp=<password>`

If using windows authentication then input username = password = `space`. The file paths that contain spaces must be enclosed in quotation marks.

See https://www.katieandemil.com/sqlpackage-exe-extract-dacpac-command-line?tab=article for more details.